# How do I set 'txindex = 1' in bitcoincore?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin.conf

How do I set 'txindex = 1' in bitcoincore?

I installed it on linux ubuntu.
I can not find the /home/bitcoin/bitcoin.conf file.

Path to '/home/bitcoin/share/examples/bitcoin.conf'The bitcoin.
conf file is found, but there is no place to set txindex = 1 inside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you installed Bitcoin Core on linux, the config file is most likely found in ~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf

Edit bitcoin.conf file and just add `txindex=1` anywhere you like on a new line, just make sure it's not commented out.